# use local graph in noflo.asCallback

Tags: noflo

I'm trying to execute a graph located in a local `graphs/` folder using the `noflo.asCallback` function.

I'm getting an error that the graph or component is not available with the base specified at the `baseDir`.

What is the correct way to us the `asCallback` function with a graph?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to the package name of the project. The name I was using was `noflo-test`, and the graph was available as `test/GraphName`, without the `noflo-` prepended.